# 'applypatch' process using too much CPU

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I have here a brand-new Samsung Galaxy Duos 2 and there's something that bothers me about the "applypatch" process. It uses too much CPU (up to 50%) and runs continuous like a service. Now, what does it do there?

I think this happened after I updated my firmware through Settings > About device > Software Update or maybe after I restored some apps from my other phone. Is this just normal like it would patch something and will stop as soon as it finishes its job or is there something else I should be alarmed? Do I need to stop it?

[image]

<sup>(Click on the image for larger version)</sup>

Comment: have you tried restarting your phone? does it help?

Comment: yes, MANY times, actually, it's still there up to now, so it is running for 3 days total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found out the problem, it's because of the Upgrading of the firmware. I brought my phone to Samsung and they found out that the firmware installed in the device is somehow not genuine (don't know about this, I got my device from Globe Telecom as brand-new.)

**Disclaimer**: this solution is for Samsung device under warranty period. Samsung said the problem occurs when you update through OTA when you have an inconsistent internet connection making the 'applypatch' running as if it cannot find all necessary files for upgrade and continuously searching and patching it. Solution to this is to backup first your device, bring it to Samsung Service Center then have them format it and install a genuine OS. After that, my device is back to normal with updated genuine Android 4.2.2 Jellybean and just have to restore my data.

If your warranty is over and if you're already rooted you can just reformat your Android device with a legit ROM and everything will be back to normal.